# How to detect different letters and numbers in a string

Tags: c++

So let's say there's a string of random and different letters and numbers in it, for example `"7GGG66HH"`. I am trying to figure out a way to detect each and individual number and letter contained in that string, and output a list showing how many types of each letter or number there were.

While attempting to solve this problem, I tried to take each individual letter and number, and put them through a dynamic array. That way I can then sort through the array and tally up how many times each letter and number appears. But the problem is that there are too many possible outcomes to chose from, so I cannot sort through each individual character manually. In addition to that, I do not know how to work the items in the array, and use it in correlation with a while loop.

So this is a separate snippet what I have so far...

```
int main()
{
  string userInput;
  cin >> userInput;

  vector<string> arrayOfCharacters(0);

  int x = 0;

  while (x < lastElemetOfTheArray)
  {
    // tally up the number of each letter and number present

    ++x;
  }

  // display the number of times each letter and number was present

  return 0;
}
```

Let's say that you input
`5AAY00UUU`

The expected output would be

```
15
2A
1Y
20
3U
```

Noticed how the first number is the number of times that character appears.

Also, I want to know if I'm thinking in the right direction by using the while loop and the dynamic array. If there is a completely different solution, or I'm using the incorrect methods, then please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Unless you're supposed to implement it yourself, then e.g. [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) could be very useful.

Comment: And if you need to implement it yourself without the help of a map, and you only allow standard 7-bit ASCII, then remember that each character is represented by a small integer value, that can also be used as an index in an array.

Comment: I read your link, and that was helpful, but could you write it as an answer and just add a basic outline of my code with `std::unordered_map`? That would be great help for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish it with the help of [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). e.g.

```
// define a map, key is the character, mapped value is used for counting
std::map<char, int> m;

// increase the count on every character
// if key does not already exist, std::map::operator[] would insert one with mapped value initialized as 0
for (auto c : userInput)
    m[c]++;

// print out the result
for (auto const& p : m)
    std::cout << p.second << p.first << std::endl;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B2Elv3FSgItus4zO)

Answer (score 0):

How big is the character set ? If simple ASCII then you can just create an array of 256 values, init all values at 0.

then :

```
for each(character in string){
    myCountArray[character]++;
}
```

This could not work with huge character set.