# Is there a way in which I can accept an input of array of numbers without accepting garbage values?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

```
Input: 30 30 30 40 40 50 50 4 4 4 4
output: 3 30 2 40 2 50 4 4
```

I have to accept these integer numbers and display the count of each unique number with the number beside the count.

I honestly don't know what condition to give to accept only till the last integer 4 of the input and not accept infinitely or some garbage values. Because all test cases do not have the same number of values as input. Please explain what function/logic I need to use to just accept the finite numbers of integers.

I used a for loop that accepted and stored values in a vector for 99 times, because the question said that the maximum number of integers that I can accept is 99. But for the above test case, 11 required integers are accepted and the rest 87 are garbage/last integer values...

It accepted 30 30 30 40 40 50 50 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 .........(till the 99th loop)

(I would've attached a screenshot of what I did if I could. I didn't do that because, 1) I was asked to code this in a contest so I don't remember the exact question as we were not allowed to bring our rough sheets out with us. 2) I couldn't make a decent attempt to solve it as I didn't even know how to accept the integers without accepting garbage values. Sorry for the uncertainty!)

Comment: Generally input is "signaled".  If this is for a programming challenge then the stream will go into a "end of input" state that will stop an input loop for you.  Have a look at this Q&A pair for the technique and what happens: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608176/read-unknown-number-of-inputs-in-c

Comment: There are numerous ways to validate input in c++. At least show some effort of what you tried already and why it fails.

Comment: Define ***random values*** as you think it applies tor your application.

Comment: How do you determine if a value is random or not?

Comment: ***Because all test cases do not have the same number of values as input.*** That is where you will need a `std::vector` instead of a fixed sized array.

Comment: Define "random values".

Comment: Please provide the code you have developed for solving this. We can help you improving and fixing the code but we are not gonna write the whole code for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57356714/how-to-detect-different-letters-and-numbers-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the numbers in a string and then extract each number from the string using the standard string stream `std::istringstream` declared in header `<sstream>`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    std::cout << "input: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, input, '\n' );

    std::map<int, size_t> m;

    int value;

    for ( std::istringstream is( input ); is >> value; )
    {
        ++m[value];
    }

    std::cout << "output: ";
    for ( const auto &p : m ) std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
input: 30 30 30 40 40 50 50 4 4 4 4
output: 4 4 30 3 40 2 50 2
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed! I didn't know about std string stream header and it's function. Thank you very much @Vlad ! But can you explain what 'const auto' does here?? I didn't exactly understand that..